# problems with conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, javascript-objects

can anyone help? I created a tab step component and I'm having problems as it progresses to the next step, I've created a method for clicking the next button for the next step, but it ignores the conditions and advances to the last step. My code:

Hello, can anyone help? I created a tab step component and I'm having problems as it progresses to the next step, I've created a method for clicking the next button for the next step, but it ignores the conditions and advances to the last step. My code:

```js
verifyTabsCoherency(){
        this.enabledTabs = [];
 

        this.enabledTabs.push( 
            { title:  this.tabstepItem[0].title , icon: this.tabstepItem[0].icon, content: this.tabstepItem[0].icon, enable: this.tabstepItem[1].enable = true, selected: this.tabstepItem[1].enable = true }
        );
        
        this.enabledTabs.push(
            { title:  this.tabstepItem[1].title, icon: this.tabstepItem[1].icon, content: this.tabstepItem[1].content, enable: this.tabstepItem[1].enable, selected: this.tabstepItem[1].selected  }
        );

        if(this.customFilter.enableStation){
            this.enabledTabs.push(
                { title:  this.tabstepItem[2].title, icon: this.tabstepItem[2].icon, content: this.tabstepItem[2].content, enable: this.tabstepItem[2].enable, selected: this.tabstepItem[2].selected  }
            );
        }

        if(this.customFilter.enableUser) {
            this.enabledTabs.push(
                { title:  this.tabstepItem[3].title, icon: this.tabstepItem[3].icon, content: this.tabstepItem[3].content, enable: this.tabstepItem[3].enable, selected: this.tabstepItem[3].selected  }
            );
        }

        if(this.customFilter.enableAccess){
            this.enabledTabs.push(
                { title:  this.tabstepItem[3].title, icon: this.tabstepItem[4].icon, content: this.tabstepItem[4].content, enable: this.tabstepItem[4].enable, selected: this.tabstepItem[4].selected  }
            );
        }

        if(this.customFilter.Companys){
            this.enabledTabs.push(
                { title:  this.tabstepItem[3].title, icon: this.tabstepItem[5].icon, content: this.tabstepItem[5].content, enable: this.tabstepItem[5].enable, selected: this.tabstepItem[5].selected  }
            );
        }

        if(this.customFilter.Customers){
            this.enabledTabs.push(
                { title:  this.tabstepItem[3].title, icon: this.tabstepItem[6].icon, content: this.tabstepItem[6].content, enable: this.tabstepItem[6].enable, selected: this.tabstepItem[6].selected  }
            )
        }

        if(this.customFilter.Sections){
            this.enabledTabs.push(
                { title:  this.tabstepItem[7].title, icon: this.tabstepItem[7].icon, content: this.tabstepItem[7].content, enable: this.tabstepItem[7].enable, selected: this.tabstepItem[7].selected  }
            )
        }
        
       resolveDate() {
        const myDateStart = new Date(this.dateStart);
        const myDateEnd = new Date(this.dateEnd);
        const myDateStartCompare = new Date(this.dateStartCompare);
        const myDateEndCompare = new Date(this.dateEndCompare);

        if ( this.dateStart && this.dateEnd ) {
                return true;
            } else { return false;}
    }   
    
    resolveCarpark(){
        const mycar = this.car.filter(car => car.checked === true);
        
        if( mycar.length > 0 || this.selectedGroupsTree.length > 0){
            return true;
        }
        else{ return false; }
    }

    resolveStations(){
        const myStation = this.stations.filter(stations => stations.checked === true);

        if( myStation.length > 0 ){
            return true;
        }
        else{ return false; }
    }
    
      resolveTabItem ( indexTo: number, validateTo: boolean ) {
        this.enabledTabs[indexTo].enable = validateTo;
        this.enabledTabs[indexTo].selected = validateTo;
    }
    
     nextTab(){
      
        if ( this.resolveDate() ) {
            this.resolveTabItem(1, true);
        } else if  ( this.resolveCarpark() ) {
            this.resolveTabItem(2, true);
        }
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by it advances to the last tab? It seems like you only have 2 tabs? 1st and 2nd index.

Comment: Sorry, I just deleted it. In fact there are four tabs and when it is the first index and clicks to go to the next index it goes to the last index

Comment: most likely your functions like this, this.resolveCarpark() is not returning true in that case except for the last one. are you sure they are returning true?

Comment: then it returns true, activates the tab and goes to the last index of the tab. I think it's something related to if

Comment: Okay now i see something quite odd with your codes. In your resolveTabItem() it will simply enable the next tab. So as the code progresses through the if else of nextTab(), each tab will just be enabled and move on, till the very last one.

Comment: , so I can not solve with if, I've tried to implement other logics but without success

Comment: Have added something to your logic at the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: glad it helps. you can accept it as the answer when you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to implement some kind of index based system to tell your logic at which tab it should stop at.

You would then pass in the index for navigating to the next tab as such.. nextTab(0) to enable 1st tab, nextTab(1) to enable 2nd tab...

```
nextTab(index){

        if ( this.resolveDate() && index==0) {
            this.resolveTabItem(1, true);

        } else if  ( this.resolveCarpark() && index==1) {
            this.resolveTabItem(2, true);

        }
}
```